# Validate XML against DTD using python on google app engine

Tags: python, xml, validation, google-app-engine, dtd

I've got validation working on client side using lxml, but I'm not quite sure how to get it work on Google App Engine, since it doesn't have the lxml package. I tried copying the whole lxml folder and place it in the root of my Google application, but it seems like it cannot use it properly. I'm guessing it has to do with the compiled .so-files and such.

Is there a way to get lxml to work on Google App Engine? If not, is there any other library that you can use to validate XML against DTD that works on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Compiled C extensions (like lxml) will not work on Google App Engine.

[PyXML](http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/) is no longer maintained, but it does have a pure-Python XML validator. See [this](http://snipplr.com/view/3316/xml-dtd-validation-for-python/) code snippet for an example.

Comment: minixsv supposedly works on http://www.familieleuthe.de/DownloadMiniXsv.html  but how do I add this to GAE?